# Pagination, filtering, sorting with Spring 4: modern approach 2016

Tags: spring, sorting, pagination, filtering

I'm wondering what it the established approach, kinda pattern, most usable solution to implement pagination, sorting and search on tables with Spring?
I feel there must exist some library or framework ready-to-use from TOP (view layer) to bottom (DAO layer).

I've searched extensively (finding [Spring DATA REST](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html) interfaces, third party libraries, like [Dandelion Tables](http://dandelion.github.io/components/datatables/) or [SpringPagination](https://github.com/paginationspring/pagination)), but still failed to find an attractive solution.

What I need is:

1. Minimum code;
2. Implementing standard Spring interfaces;
3. Solution for View layer (JS, JSP or Thymeleaf), Controllers and Service/DAO layers with nothing to re-invent and minimum to re-work;

Please, share knowledge how do you cope with this seemingly everyday task?

Thank you for answering!